# AJAX + jQuery Deferred: execution sequence

Tags: ajax, jquery-deferred

Task: get data from server with $.post, process them by method .success(), after that call some function.

```
    var t;
    $.when($.post("get_json.php", function(res) {
      t = res;
    }, 'json')).done(function() {
      console.log(t);
    });
```

Do I understand correctly that the Deferred method .done() is executed after .success is done (ie t = res)?
But why "console.log(t)" shows "undefined"?
Is .done() fires after request, but before .success()?

Answer (score 0):

Passing a "success" callback to `$.post()` is an alternative to the (preferred) chaining of `.done(...)`. Do one or the other, not both, then you don't need to worry about the execution order.

Also, unless you have a decent caching strategy for async data, you shouldn't be setting `t` as an outer var.

```
$.post("get_json.php", ...).done(function(t) {
    console.log(t);
    //do awesome things with t here
});
```

Caching would be something like this :

```
var asyncCache = {};

...

function get_t() {
    return (asyncCache.t) ? $.when(asyncCache.t) : $.post("get_json.php", ...).done(function(t)  {
        asyncCache.t = t;
    });
}

...

get_t().done(function(t) {
    console.log(t);
    //do awesome things with t here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$.when()` is ONLY needed when you have multiple promises and you want to wait for all of them to complete.  You simply don't need it at all for your single ajax call.  You can just do it like this:

```
$.post("get_json.php").done(function(t) {
    // use the results of the ajax call here
    console.log(t);
});
```

---

In addition, your code example was using BOTH a success callback function AND a `.done()` handler.  Pick one of the other, not both as they are different ways of getting a callback when the ajax call is done.  I'd suggest the promise implementation above because it's more flexible.  But, you could also use just the success handler:

```
$.post("get_json.php", function(t) {
    // use the results of the ajax call here
    console.log(t);
}, 'json');
```

---

Note, when you have an asynchronous operation like this, you need to consume the results of the ajax call in the success callback (or the promise callback) or call some function from there and pass it the data.  You do not want to put the data into a global variable or a variable in a higher scope because other code will simply have no way of knowing when the data is ready and when it is not.  Put your action in the callback.

---

If you have more than one ajax call that you want to wait for, then you can do it like this:

```
$.when($.post("get_json.php"), $.post("get_json2.php")).done(function(r1, r2) {
    // use the results of the ajax call here
    console.log(r1[0]);    // results from first ajax call
    console.log(r2[0]);    // results from second ajax call
});
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! But I deliberately simplified his example. In reality, I need to make two AJAX call, each of which produces changes in global variables (or in DOM elements). .done() should work when both queries will make these changes.

Comment: @user3882513 - then your question should show at least two ajax calls.  I've added an example of using `$.when()` to my answer with two ajax calls and getting the results from those ajax calls